# Exporting Numbers as Text in DataGridView in VB.Net to CSV

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview, export-to-csv

I got this tutorial from [DataGridView to CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686852/datagridview-to-csv-file) and I am having issues with one of the fields that consists of numbers especially the ones that start with 0.

```
   Dim headers = (From header As DataGridViewColumn In PadGridView.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)()
                   Select header.HeaderText).ToArray
    Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In PadGridView.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
               Where Not row.IsNewRow
               Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("export.csv")
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headers))
        For Each r In rows
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
        Next
    End Using
    Process.Start("export.csv")
End Sub
```

Current Output:

- 2.97E+104
- 18523696 which is supposed to be 018523696

Is there a possible way to export all fields as text, so the set of numbers wont get shortened or formatted differently?

Thank you in advance/

Comment: both of the issues you have listed in bullet points are a result of number formatting in the spreadsheet itself. Point#1 is caused when the format is "General", the exponent will be resolved if the format is changed to "Number" with "0 decimal precision". Point#2 is formatted as "General/Number" but must be "Text" to show the leading 0. Do you have control over what's inserted into the spreadsheet and how it's formatted? If not, you may need to format the cells before getting data out of them

Comment: The data is coming from a database that I have no control in changing, is there another way? Maybe add a single quote to that specific field so it will be treated as text?

Comment: Well, for the numbers you can select the column and use xlRange.NumberFormat = "0" to unwrap the exponent notation before you do your select. However, for text, the format needs to be changed before/while data is inserted, or you instantly lose the leading 0...changing the number format later will not bring the 0 back unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial on how to do this? I'm sill confused where to start adjusting @soohoonigan

Comment: I just made a test program, filled up a datagridview with numbers like those in your examples, and pasted your export code into it...and it worked perfect. You may need to look at the code that fills the datagridview in the first place, step through it and see where your numbers are getting altered...because your export code works fine.

Comment: @soohoonigan do you know another trick on how to fix it in the exporting? I was thinking maybe I can just add a ' (single quote) in front of each number so it will be treated as text? because the array that is being put in the datagridview is something like this: myGridView.DataSource = arrayDataRows

Comment: If your datagridview is bound to a datasource, then all you need to do is change some settings in the datagridview. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45b44816-29cf-480c-9539-47183451c96f/datagridview-scientific-notation?forum=Vsexpressvcs) for how to stop showing exponents. For text, it's the same thing, just make sure the style for text columns isn't set to number, and the leading 0's won't disappear.

Comment: @soohoonigan I got it, thanks! Do you by any chance know how to export the ones that are Visible = true on the data grid view? Because right now, even the ones that are hidden are being exported. thank you

Comment: adding that to your linq where-clause would probably be the easiest way

Comment: What do you mean? Kind of confused @soohoonigan